# What does this matlab code do and how should i implement it

Tags: serial-port, matlab

i bought a DIY project an it has this coding can somebody explain that waht does this code do. i have knowledge of C and C++ just haven't worked on MatlaB before.
 the project is to read an sms using AT commands and then processing it through an avr kit
since i am unaware of matlab programming i need to understand what does this particular code do and how to implement it in matlab as i am getting a error saying(undefined bluetooth)

```
while(1)
    flag1=0;
    flag2=0;
    i=0;
    j=1;
    count=0;
    fwrite(bluetooth,65)
    fwrite(bluetooth,84)
    fwrite(bluetooth,43)
    fwrite(bluetooth,67)
    fwrite(bluetooth,77)
    fwrite(bluetooth,71)
    fwrite(bluetooth,76)
    fwrite(bluetooth,61)
    fwrite(bluetooth,34)
    fwrite(bluetooth,82)
    fwrite(bluetooth,69)
    fwrite(bluetooth,67)
    fwrite(bluetooth,32)
    fwrite(bluetooth,85)
    fwrite(bluetooth,78)
    fwrite(bluetooth,82)
    fwrite(bluetooth,69)
    fwrite(bluetooth,65)
    fwrite(bluetooth,68)
    fwrite(bluetooth,34)
    fwrite(bluetooth,13)
    a=fread(bluetooth,1)
    if(a==13)
        a=fread(bluetooth,1)
        if(a==10)
            28
            while(flag1==0)
                a=fread(bluetooth,1)
                if(a==79)
                    count=count+1
                end
                if(a==75)
                    count=count+1
                end
                if(a==10)
                    flag1=1
                end
            end
        end
    end
    if(count~=2)
        while(flag2==0)
            a=fread(bluetooth,1)
            i=i+1;
            if(j>0)
                fopen(pc_uc)
                j=j-1;
            end
            fwrite(pc_uc,a)
            if(a==13)
                flag2=1
            end
        end
        for i=1:7
            a=fread(bluetooth,1)
        end
        fclose(bluetooth)
        fclose(pc_uc)
        fopen(bluetooth)
    end
end
```

Comment: `bluetooth` is used as a file identifier here and you are getting an "undefined" error for it because it is indeed undefined. There should be some extra code before the while-loop initializing it.

Comment: I think I have a pretty accurate break-down of what the code is doing? Any comments, or will you accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very pretty code, but here's what it does, as far as I can tell:

1. Send the [SMS command](http://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/at-cmgl-text-mode/):

   ```
   AT+CMGL="REC UNREAD"
   ```
2. Check for carriage return, `<CR>` (ASCII code 13)
3. Check for line feed, `<LF>` (ASCII code 10)
4. Read in characters until it reads in `OK` or a `<LF>`.
5. If it did not receive an `OK`, copy data to `pc_us` (no idea what that is) until it hits a `<CR>` in `bluetooth`, read a few extra bytes from `bluetooth` (clearing a buffer?), then close and r-open `bluetooth`.